# How to get item's position in a list?

Tags: python, list

I am iterating over a list and I want to print out the index of the item if it meets a certain condition. How would I do this?

Example:

```
testlist = [1,2,3,5,3,1,2,1,6]
for item in testlist:
    if item == 1:
        print position
```

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Hmmm.  There was an answer with a list comprehension here, but it's disappeared.

Here:

```
 [i for i,x in enumerate(testlist) if x == 1]
```

Example:

```
>>> testlist
[1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 6]
>>> [i for i,x in enumerate(testlist) if x == 1]
[0, 5, 7]
```

Update:

Okay, you want a generator expression, we'll have a generator expression.  Here's the list comprehension again, in a for loop:

```
>>> for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(testlist) if x == 1]:
...     print i
... 
0
5
7
```

Now we'll construct a generator...

```
>>> (i for i,x in enumerate(testlist) if x == 1)
<generator object at 0x6b508>
>>> for i in (i for i,x in enumerate(testlist) if x == 1):
...     print i
... 
0
5
7
```

and niftily enough, we can assign that to a variable, and use it from there...

```
>>> gen = (i for i,x in enumerate(testlist) if x == 1)
>>> for i in gen: print i
... 
0
5
7
```

And to think I used to write FORTRAN.

Comment: This is the best answer here, IMO. It's clear and succinct, and you actually capture the index values, so it's extensible (you can print them, pass them to another func., etc.) Only improvement is to use a generator expression for cases with many matches. http://is.gd/brzl

Comment: After probably 25 years of questioning functional programming, I think I'm finally getting the clue.  list comprehension is da bomb.

Comment: Single word variables make it harder to comprehend your code, especially in programming examples.

Comment: I presume you mean "single letter" and frankly, a longer name in this example would have no more information content.

Comment: Thanks for great answer.  I think @nailer's comment might relate to the fact that you use 'i' in two different contexts in a single line in the generator example; one inside the comprehension, and the other to iterate through it.  I know it threw me off for a second.

Comment: @CharlieMartin You use 'i' for the index rather than the item per the one common convention for single character variables. Naming the index 'index' and the item 'item' would remove ambiguity. Additionally you're replying to a parent that used 'item' and 'position' and it's good manners not to unnecessarily rename parts of the original code in your answer.

Comment: Hm.  In each case, the i outside the list comprehension or generator is exactly what's being gathered up as i inside.  I'd find it confusing to have two different names for it.

Comment: Super syntax :o) You can easily get a command line parameter. Let there is an array of arguments: `args = ['x', '-p1', 'v1', '-p2', 'v2']`. Then the command `args[[i for i, x in enumerate(args) if x == '-p1'][0] + 1]` returns `'v1'`

Answer (score 198):

What about the following?

```
print testlist.index(element)
```

If you are not sure whether the element to look for is actually in the list, you can add a preliminary check, like

```
if element in testlist:
    print testlist.index(element)
```

or

```
print(testlist.index(element) if element in testlist else None)
```

or the "pythonic way", which I don't like so much because code is less clear, but sometimes is more efficient,

```
try:
    print testlist.index(element)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: instead of testing before accessing, you could also just try and check for `ValueError`

Comment: I think that he wants for find all occurrences, you seem to give only the first one.

Comment: @tfv I don't see how you can come to such conclusion since the question says "item" and not "items".

Answer (score 43):

Use enumerate:

```
testlist = [1,2,3,5,3,1,2,1,6]
for position, item in enumerate(testlist):
    if item == 1:
        print position
```

Answer (score 11):

```
for i in xrange(len(testlist)):
  if testlist[i] == 1:
    print i
```

xrange instead of range as requested (see comments).

Comment: replace range() with xrange() -- range() creates a list, xrange() creates a iterator. xrange() uses waaaay less memory, and the inital call is faster.

Comment: I agree for large lists in python 2 programs. Note that 'range' will still work in python 3 though (and work like xrange IIRC). 'xrange' is going the way of the dinosaurs.

Comment: Update: `xrange` is depracted in Python 3.x, as the new `range` is the old `xrange`

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way to do this:

```
try:
   id = testlist.index('1')
   print testlist[id]
except ValueError:
   print "Not Found"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the below:

```
testlist = [1,2,3,5,3,1,2,1,6]    
position=0
for i in testlist:
   if i == 1:
      print(position)
   position=position+1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[x for x in range(len(testlist)) if testlist[x]==1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list got large enough and you only expected to find the value in a sparse number of indices, consider that this code *could* execute much faster because you don't have to iterate every value in the list.

```
lookingFor = 1
i = 0
index = 0
try:
  while i < len(testlist):
    index = testlist.index(lookingFor,i)
    i = index + 1
    print index
except ValueError: #testlist.index() cannot find lookingFor
  pass
```

If you expect to find the value a lot you should probably just append "index" to a list and print the list at the end to save time per iteration.

Comment: I did some timing tests.  The list comprehension technique runs 38% faster than this code.  (I replaced your print statement with a outputlist.append call)

Comment: I also did some tests with list sizes of 100000 random values between 1 and 100. The code I wrote was in some cases twice as fast. No time testing is comparable to poster's application (they must test themselves to be sure, of course). I apologize if my opinion was detrimental to this post.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it might be useful to use the curselection() method from thte Tkinter library:

```
from Tkinter import * 
listbox.curselection()
```

This method works on Tkinter listbox widgets, so you'll need to construct one of them instead of a list.

This will return a position like this:

**('0',)** (although later versions of Tkinter may return a list of ints instead)

Which is for the first position and the number will change according to the item position.

For more information, see this page:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm

Greetings.

Comment: Interesting idea. Since this requires importing the entire Tkinter library, though, it's not the most efficient way to solve the problem.

Comment: This is such an inefficient and meandering path that I'd say it's a wrong answer, even if it somewhat addresses the question.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why complicate things?

```
testlist = [1,2,3,5,3,1,2,1,6]
for position, item in enumerate(testlist):
    if item == 1:
        print position
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = list(map(int,input().split(",")))
num = int(input())
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] == num:
        print(i)
```

Explanation:

Taken a list of integer "l" (separated by commas) in line 1.
Taken a integer "num" in line 2.
Used for loop in line 3 to traverse inside the list and checking if numbers(of the list) meets the given number(num) then it will print the index of the number inside the list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read How to Answer and edit your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate complete example along with the `input_list` which has `searies1` (example: input_list[0]) in which you want to do a lookup of `series2` (example: input_list[1]) and get indexes of series2 if it exists in series1.

Note: Your `certain condition` will go in lambda expression if conditions are simple

```
input_list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,3,7]]
series1 = input_list[0]
series2 = input_list[1]
idx_list = list(map(lambda item: series1.index(item) if item in series1 else None, series2))
print(idx_list)
```

output:

```
[0, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
testlist = [1,2,3,5,3,1,2,1,6]
num = 1
for item in range(len(testlist)):
    if testlist[item] == num:
        print(item)
```

Comment: test list != testlist

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer, @Shivam Raj .

Answer (score -1):

What about trying

```py
list_ = ["pen", "david"]
for i in list_:
    list_.index(i)
```

The code literally takes each object and parses the postion of `i`

Additionally if you wanted to check a specific element you could try:

```py
list_ = ["pen", "david"]
for i in list_:
    if list_.index(i) == 0:
        print(i, list_.index(i))
```

Comment: The question was asked in 2008! Isn't it a bit late to answer it now?

Answer (score -2):

```
testlist = [1,2,3,5,3,1,2,1,6]
for id, value in enumerate(testlist):
    if id == 1:
        print testlist[id]
```

I guess that it's exacly what you want. ;-)
'id' will be always the index of the values on the list.