# How to find the position of an element in a list , in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
for s in stocks_list:
    print s
```

how do I know what "position" s is in? So that I can do **stocks_list[4]** in the future?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/python-get-position-in-list

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
for index, s in enumerate(stocks_list):
    print index, s
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I accidentally downvoted. Could you please edit your answer so that I undo my downvote?

Comment: @ArturBarseghyan you could just upvote twice, to cancel the effect and establish an upvote.

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider:

The message I get is "You last voted on this answer Jun 15 at 22:08. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Answer (score 90):

If you know what you're looking for ahead of time you can use the index method:

```
>>> stocks_list = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG']
>>> stocks_list.index('MSFT')
1
>>> stocks_list.index('GOOG')
2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[x for x in range(len(stocks_list)) if stocks_list[x]=='MSFT']
```

Answer (score 0):

The position is called by `stocks_list.index(s)`, for example:

```py
for s in stocks_list:
    print(stocks_list.index(s))
```

Comment: This is already stated by [the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7532611/3025856). When answering questions with existing answers, be sure to review those answers, and only add a new answer if you have a different solution, or a substantially improved explanation. Later, when you have a bit more reputation, you'll also be able to upvote existing answers in order to validate their guidance.

Comment: No it wasn't. That answer only said  "If you know what you're looking for ahead of time" while mine does not necessitate that.