# Python - most efficient way of matching a list

Tags: python, loops

Say for example I have a list of 7 numbers, let's call it 'lineA' and I have 50 lines of numbers below and I want to see if 'lineA' matches my 50 lines EXACTLY in that order. What is the quickest (time-wise)/most efficient way of doing it? A loop? Or any other method?

```
lineA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

lineTwo = [1,33,40,44,45,1,2]
lineThree = [2,13,22,41,50,8,9]
lineFour = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
lineFive = etc.....(repeat this 50 times)
```

Thank you

Comment: Why are you having **50** lists in the first place?

Comment: If you have 2 or more variables with numbers in their names, you almost certainly wanted a list of lists, not 50 variables.

Comment: So what do you want your output to be, a simple bool?

Comment: Do you want "quickest to write" or "quickest to run"?

Comment: Output should just be a simple print saying 'lineA matches lineFour' or whatever line it matches.

Comment: quickest to run.....however, I would like it to be quick to write as well... I don't know if that's possible though?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/python-get-position-in-list
That link and the fact that `[1, 2] == [1, 2]` -> `True` answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare two lists with the `==` operator:

```
if lineA == lineOne:
    print 'they match!'
```

Now, keep all your lines in a list:

```
lines = [lineOne, lineTwo, lineThree, ..., lineFifty]
```

And just find the lines that match:

```
matches = [line for line in lines if line == lineA]
```

You can't really get more efficient than comparing each line (`O(n)`). *UNLESS* you sort your input first. Then you could use the `bisect` module and get an `O(log n)` performance. Do this if you want to compare `lineB, lineC, lineZ` with `lines` as well. Otherwise don't bother, because sorting will essentially compare all the lines as well for `O(n * log n)`...

Comment: What would be the point of `matches`? All it reveals is how many lines matched.

Comment: Use enumerate to get the index position to store in matches instead of the list that matches.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a list containing all your lists.

```
lines = [lineOne, lineTwo, ..., lineFifty]
```

Then you can use the following:

```
outs = [ind for ind,val in enumerate(lines) if val == lineA]
```

This comprehension is `O(n)` I believe since it just checks each value in `lines` once. `outs` now tells you where `lines` contains a list equal to `lineA`. Plus it's a one-liner which is about as 'fast to write' as you can get. Using the indices you can work out which `line` was matched.

Comment: This is a better answer than Daren Thomas' because it stores the index instead of just the same list over and over.

Comment: I agree, seems like having the index could be useful - am I the only one who doesn't get the use case of this question at all?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy [array_equal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) should be able to improve runtime over anything else said here; frankly you can't do better than comparing elements lexographically i.e. what the list == operator does. unless this is a streaming list or there is some other aspect you are omitting.

a benchmark on my *very* slow computer: you should be able to get a larger difference

```
import timeit

testeq= """\
a = [ range(randint(0,10),100) for x in xrange(500)]
b = range(5,100)
c = [list for list in a if list==b ]
"""

testnpeq= """
a = numpy.array([ range(randint(0,10),100) for x in xrange(500)])
b = numpy.array(range(5,100))
c = numpy.where(array_equal(a,b))
"""


print 'using == operator', timeit.timeit(testeq, setup="from random\
 import randint", number = 10000)

print 'using np operator', timeit.timeit(testeq, setup="from random\
 import randint\nimport numpy as np", number = 10000)
```

> > using == operator 13.5805370808
> >
> > using np operator 12.8217720985

note: both are using *different* random arrays. You should get even faster run times if you use the same array.

tl;dr only way to do a comparison is lexographically; use numpy / C