# Im supposed to make a treasure hunt lab and i dont understand how to do any of it

Tags: arrays

Write a program where the user enters a String containing only the ‘N” letters and 
possibly a single ‘T’. When there is no ‘T’ the program will print “No Treasure. When 
there is a ‘T’ the program will tell the user the index of the ‘T’ (treasure).

The data will be read as a String and then converted to a char array for processing.

can anybody help me out?

Comment: What is your programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Just find a command to read in Strings from the console or search how to parse program arguments. This depends on how your input is provided.

Then find out how to convert a String to a char array (reading documentations helps for this).

And last find out how to check a char array for several letters (hint: Ascii tables).

The rest should be very easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way you can ask for user input and store it in a string is with the raw_input command:

```
x = raw_input('Please enter a string with at most one T')
```

You can create an array by using the list function - mylist = list(x). To test whether that list has a certain character you can use

```
for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x == 'T']:
    print('There is a T at position ',i+1) #Add one if preferred due to zero indexing
```

where i is the index (position) and x is the value in your list. (from [How to get item's position in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/python-get-position-in-list))