# Is there a way to get the run count of a for loop not using range?

Tags: python

If I have a for loop using a range like this:

```
for x in range(10):
```

then in order to get the count, it's just x.  But say I have a for loop using a list:

```
layer = [somedata,someotherdata...etc]
for row in layer:
     print #the number the loop is on
```

Is there a way to do this besides specifying an integer count variable and incrementing it each run through, like this?

```
layer = [somedata]
count = 0
for row in layer:
    print count
    count += 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - get position in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/python-get-position-in-list)

Answer (score 10):

You can use `enumerate`. This will give you a count of every iteration and the value you're iterating.

Note: like `range` you can specify at what index to begin counting.

```
for count, row in enumerate(layer):
    print count
```

Answer (score 3):

```
layer = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for index, value in enumerate(layer):
    print 'Index: {} Value: {}'.format(index,value)
```

Output

```
Index: 0 Value: a
Index: 1 Value: b
Index: 2 Value: c
Index: 3 Value: d
```