# Python: Find index of first instance of zero in an array, if none are found return None

Tags: python, arrays

Given an array like this

```
a1= np.array([0,2,0,3])
```

if i want to return index of the first zero I do simply:

```
(a1==0).argmax(axis=0)
>> 0
```

however for the list like this:

```
a2= np.array([1,2,3,3])
```

It returns the same thing although the array does not have any zeros.

```
(a2==0).argmax(axis=0)
>> 0
```

How can I distinguish between these situations? Is it possible to impose that if an array does not have any zeros, the algorithm should return None?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: find position of element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260811/python-find-position-of-element-in-array)

Comment: Why does `.find` as suggested in the linked duplicate not work? In fact, if you want a numpy solution, [`np.argwhere()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) exists. Why would you use `argmax()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is a zero.

```
condition = a2 == 0
index = condition.argmax() if condition.any() else None
```

I think it's better to use `np.where()` in this case because it can be achieved with only one pass over the array, while both `.argmax()` and `.any()` will have to go through it again.

```
index = np.where(a2 == 0)[0]      # will be empty if none are found
index = index[0] if index else None
```

Comment: I actually like the first answer more! Thanks!

Comment: @kikatuso Why would you ever use `argmax()` for a janky, improvised `argwhere()`?