# When iterating through a list in python, how can I get the current number of "i"?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, iterator

I have a list and am iteratively performing a function on each item. I am trying to print out how far through the iteration the script is. The problem is that I can't easily get the position.

Here is what I have so far, but it generates a `ValueError: 'item' is not in list`.:

```
that_number = len(mylist)
for i in mylist: 
     this_number = mylist.index(i)
     print this_number, " out of ", that_number
     DO SOMETHING
print "Done!"
```

I am aiming for the output:

```
1 out of 3
2 out of 3
3 out of 3
Done!
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/python-get-position-in-list) is related in that it is trying to find the position in a list, however is there a valid way of getting the element position without using `enumerate`?

Comment: The code you've shown shouldn't produce the error you describe, and why not use `enumerate`, anyway?

Comment: There are problems of correctness and efficiency when using the ``index`` function: (i) Cannot handle duplicated elements; (ii) Quadratic complexity where it is really unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

the `enumerate()` function really gives you what you want.  For other ways to do it though, you can do a for loop over a range:

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
     print myList[i], "at index", i
```

`range(len(myList))` creates a list from `0` to `len(myList) - 1` so you can use that to index into each element of the list.

### Use a Generator Instead

For long lists creating another list the size of your original to loop over may be undesirable.  Here is the same code as above for both python2 and 3 which will execute a for loop over a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead of a list.

#### Python 2

For Python 2, just use `xrange` instead of `range`:

```
for i in xrange(len(myList)):
     print myList[i], "at index", i
```

#### Python 3

For Python 3 `range` returns a generator, so lets just change the print statement:

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
     print(myList[i], "at index", i)
```

Comment: Lots of nice little nugget extras in this clear answer: `enumerate`, `xrange`, `print`-as-function, generator understanding

Answer (score 0):

mmm, you'll have issue with duplicates on your list. If it's only for debugging/display purposes

```
that_number = len(mylist)
this_number=0
for i in mylist: 
   this_number+=1
   print this_number, " out of ", that_number
   DO SOMETHING

print "Done!"
```

how would you deal with a list containing [1,2,3,2,1] ?