# How to make the loop change the items in the list sequentially?

Tags: python, list, loops

i want to make a loop, that every time it runs, the corresponding item in a list is changed.

for example:

```
list=[10, 20, 30]
```

the first run will add 1 to 10
the second rung will subtract 5 from 20
the third run will add 2 to 30
and the loop starts over again.

how can i do this? thanks for answering!

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do? or the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: i don't know the syntax of modifying certain item in the list based on the times if runs of the loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - get position in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/python-get-position-in-list)

Answer (score 3):

You may use the [built-in `zip` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) like this:

```
changes = [1, -5, 2]
data = [10, 20, 30]

result = [(a + b) for a, b in zip(data, changes)]
```

and then

```
>>> result
[11, 15, 32]
```

If you want to do that in a loop, go ahead:

```
while <your condition>:
    data = [(a + b) for a, b in zip(data, changes)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As a simple example you can create a rules `dict` add add each value per index.

```
rules = {1: 1, 2: -5, 3: 2}
my_list = [10, 20, 30]

print [v + rules[i+1] for i, v in enumerate(my_list[:])]
```

We will iterate at each index and add the corresponded rule from `rules` if the key won't exists at the `rules` dict you will get a [raise](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) of [`KeyError`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError)

You ca further read more on `lists` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and on python `list comprehension` [here](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
if i == 0:
    l[0] += 1
elif i == 1:
    l[1] -= 5
elif i == 2:
    l[2] += 2

print l
```

Comment: You can do it that way, but at least change `l[0] += 1` to `l[i] += 1`