# How to find in a list what thats number python3

Tags: python-3.4

Im trying to find out the number of where X is in the list e.g:
if i had a list like: `['a','b','c','d']` and i have 'c' how would i find where it is in the list, so that it would print '2' (as thats where it is in the list)
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get item's position in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/how-to-get-items-position-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in method `list.index`

If you wanna know where is 'c':

`l = ['a','b','c']`

`l.index('c')`

Comment: If Marques provided an answer that is actually a solution to your problem, you should mark his answer as solution.