# How to display a limited amount of values from a list?

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python and I am struggling to display a specific amount of values from a list using `for`.

Here is an example of what I want to do in Java:

```
for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){
   System.out.println(list(i));
}
```

How can I write this code in python ?

Comment: `for i in xrange(0, 6):
    print i`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get item's position in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/how-to-get-items-position-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is close in syntax to JavaScript, Java & C. Blocks are identified by tabs or spaces instead of braces. Range here is used to return an array consisting of 5 integers.
Think of this loop as a for in loop (used to loop through object values in JS).

```
for i in range(5):
  print(yourCustomList[i])
```

If you want to loop through the index of a string or array substitute `range()` with `range(len(array))`.

Even better, you can just have Python loop through the values instead of the indexes.

```
for i in yourCustomList[:5]:
  print(i)
```

Comment: Do you mean `list[i]`?

Comment: Also, please don't use `list` as a variable name for a list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list slicing, which takes the notation of `[start:end]`

For example:

```
my_list = ['some', 'stuff', 'in', 'this', 'list', 'of', 'mine']
print(my_list[0:5])
```

Comment: FWIW, if the start is `0` (or the end is the end of the list), it's common to leave them off:  `my_list[:5]` or `my_list[2:]`.  There's also an optional step:  `my_list[:5:2]`