# Name Error "i" is not defined when attempting to print(i) after using it in a For Loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to learn about web scraping. I am getting the position of "Basic EPS" from the webpage using a generator found [How to get item's position in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/how-to-get-items-position-in-a-list). However I am receiving this error message:

```
gen = (i for i,x in enumerate(div) if x == eps)
for i in gen: print(i)
--->  print(i)
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

My code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

PAGE ="https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/QAN.AX/financials?p=QAN.AX"
result = requests.get(PAGE)

type(result)
source = result.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find_all('div', class_='rw-expnded')
#pprint.pprint(div)
eps = soup.find('div', title='Basic EPS')
#pprint.pprint(eps)
gen = (i for i,x in enumerate(div) if x == eps)
for i in gen: print(i)
print(i)
```

I am a bit confused by this as I didn't think I needed to define "i". I then am planning to use "i" in an arithmetic calculation to find a position of another section so the expected result should be 10 as an int.

Does anyone have any tips?

EDIT: To add the outputs for `div` and `eps`.
`print(div)` has huge output that exceeds maximum characters but contains:

```
<div class="D(ib) Va(m) Ell Mt(-3px) W(215px)--mv2 W(200px) undefined" data-reactid="286" title="Basic EPS"><span class="Va(m)" data-reactid="287">Basic EPS</span></div>
```

`print(eps)`

```
<div class="D(ib) Va(m) Ell Mt(-3px) W(215px)--mv2 W(200px) undefined" data-reactid="286" title="Basic EPS"><span class="Va(m)" data-reactid="287">Basic EPS</span></div>
```

Comment: It's because your loop is never executed. Make sure that `gen` is not empty.

Comment: Does that mean making sure that div and eps have values?

Comment: You need to be sure that `div` is not empty and `x == eps` will be `True` at least once. So there will be value(s) in the `gen` to iterate over.

Comment: Thought that might have been the case. Have tried that, there is exactly one instance of `x == eps` within `div`. At position 10 in the list.

Comment: So you should see it printed into the screen, before the exception is raised. But when I run your code, it doesn't print any output, so `gen` is empty.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, although `eps` is appearing in `div`, it is part of a much bigger amount of code within the position of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added inline comments

```py
# below i, x are in inside a list-comprehension, so they are not avail to print in the main program
gen = (i for i,x in enumerate(div) if x == eps) 

# If any item is present in gen, only then `i` gets initialized and printed
for i in gen: print(i)

# following can give you a NameError if `i` did not get initialized before this step.
print(i)
```

It is not suggestible to `print(i)` like above but if you want to print last item of gen, then do the following

```py
if gen:
    print(i)
```

or a better option

```py
if gen:
    print(gen[-1])
```